# How to check data lineage on azure databricks and HDinsight?

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-hdinsight, data-lineage

I have notebooks that performs transformation in tables stored in dbfs(databricks file system).I want to capture and display the data lineage. Additionally i want to know how to do the same in hdinsight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spline is derived from the words Spark and Lineage. It is a tool which is used to visualize and track how the data changes over time. Spline provides a GUI where the user can view and analyze how the data transforms to give rise to the insights.

You may checkout article which explains [Spark Data Lineage on Databricks Notebook using Spline](https://blogs.knowledgelens.com/index.php/2019/11/20/spark-data-lineage-on-databricks-notebook-using-spline/) and [Data Lineage Tracking And Visualization Solution](https://absaoss.github.io/spline/blog.html).

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.